# Error while deploying a smart contract to a local hardhat node

Tags: next.js, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

Getting the following two errors when I deploy my contract to my local hardhat node:

**Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getAvatar", network="unknown", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.6.5)**

**Error: network does not support ENS (operation="lookupAddress", network="unknown", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.6.5)**

I'm using ethers, hardhat, and rainbow kit wallet in a next.js app. The rest of my code appears to be working, but I'm still getting these errors in the console on the initial load. Here is my deploy script that I'm running on hardhat:

```
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
  const NFTMarketplace = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarketplace");
  const nftMarketplace = await NFTMarketplace.deploy();
  await nftMarketplace.deployed();
  console.log("nftMarketplace deployed to:", nftMarketplace.address);

  fs.writeFileSync(
    "./config.js",
    `
  export const marketplaceAddress = "${nftMarketplace.address}"
  `
  );
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *network does not support ENS*

[ENS](https://docs.ens.domains/) stands for Ethereum Name Service. It's a decentralized alternative to DNS (Domain Name Service) on the Ethereum network.

The [rainbowkit](https://github.com/rainbow-me/rainbowkit) wallet is trying to query Hardhat for an ENS name of an address and its avatar, however Hardhat emulator does not support ENS.